# Can I study in Germany with a criminal record?

Tags: germany, criminal-records

I am a Chinese national who has lived in the US for 15+ years. I have a drug-related criminal charge against me from the US but I left the country before my court date (my lawyer did not feel like it was worth it for me to stick around). This was my first time offence, and non-violent.

I'd like to study in Germany for a masters degree but I'm worried this legal obstacle will prevent me from getting a student visa. I understand that the application asks for "convictions". Since I was not convicted (I never went to court) is it super risky for me to say no and leave it at that? I know there is an element of risk involved but I'm also wondering if my Chinese passport will play a role here. Are the German authorities likely to look into my criminal history both in the US (as I've lived there for so long) as well as China (I am a Chinese citizen; FYI I have no record in China). Or is it better to simply be honest and tell the truth (in which case I'm worried I will be denied the visa anyways).

Seeing as how I need to have an acceptance letter from a German university before I apply I'd like to be more informed about my options before I start prepping my university applications.

Comment: To be convicted, you do not need to go to court. You can have an additional charge if you do not go to court if they required you. Additional, "crime" is only a part of offenses you can get in court. If you lawyer didn't require you, it seems something minor (and possibly not a crime). You should ask your lawyers, and then add here information. It is too vague. Anyway, never lie

Comment: I am not giving you advice either way, but I think it is highly unlikely that the German authorities will find out about those kind of charges in the US.